# Bash: Sending HTML with an attached file?

Tags: html, linux, bash, email, attachment

I'm looking for a way to send an HTML email from bash with an attached file.
I've tried the following line, but it doesn't work 100%. The below line sends an HTML email, but there is no attached file:

```
( cat body.html ; uuencode in-attachfile.txt out-attachfile.txt ) | mail -s "$(echo -e "my subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" foo@example.com
```

If I remove the `Content-Type: text/html` to indicate this is an HTML email then the attachment works:

```
( cat body.html ; uuencode in-attachfile.txt out-attachfile.txt ) | mail -s "$(echo -e "my subject")" foo@example.com
```

How can I have both?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
( cat body.html; uuencode in-attachfile.txt out-attachfile.txt ) | mail -s "my subject" -a "Content-Type: text/html" foo@example.com
```

You may want to send the attachment using MIME (via mutt, for example). See [this](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.html) for more information.

Comment: My `mail` doesn't have an `-a` option... I'm running centOS.

Comment: can you use sendmail? Also, I think can use a multi-part mime type to embed a document inside html. Try looking at a raw document that has all the features built in that you need and construct from there. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Can you please give me an example of MIME with sendmail. Thanks.

Comment: @Dennis I can't install a 3rd party software, like `mutt`, on this machine.